# Top Required Error in Ruby Cucumber - Unable to execute the code

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have written a small piece of code just for launch a browser but I'm getting this error:

> C:/Users/KASTURIPARIDA/RubymineProjects/Project1/features/support/driversettings.rb:6:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13:in`
>   ' C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
>   C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in`'
>   -e:1:in `load'

Here below are all the code:

Support:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = 'C:\Ruby193\bin\chromedriver.exe'

$driver=watir::Browser.new :Chrome

wait 5
```

Feature:

```
Feature: Application
  Scenario:  Login to Open
    And I have account with Opencart and launch page
```

Step definition:

```
And(/^I have account with Opencart and launch page$/) do
  puts "browser loading"
  $driver.goto("https://www.facebook.com/")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Support

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = 'C:\Ruby193\bin\chromedriver.exe'

$driver = Watir::Browser.new('chrome')
```

Hope it helps.